# Php pagination on 30 records limit

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm trying to do something like membership profile visitors.

->Free members can see 10 profile visitors.

->Paid members can see 230 profile visitors.

->Per page records 9

How do I set pagination on these numbers.

This is what I'm trying.

```
$limit = ($data['user']['membership']['name'] =='Free' ? '10' : '30');

$query("SELECT * FROM profilevisitors WHERE user_id=".$id." LIMIT " .$limit. " , " $??);
```

This is where I'm lost.

Comment: "*This is where I'm lost.*" - All you have are 2 lines of code. Come on. And you almost definitely don't want to be using variable functions.

Comment: I have code more than that, but I didn't post it because I want a general idea.

And It's on wordpress, which is new for me.

Should I post the whole code ?

Comment: Post the relevant code. Let us know what's not working and what you would like your code to do instead. The more specific you are the easier it is for us to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set a page number through get e.g `url.com?page=1` and set your views per page

```
$pageNumber = (!isset($_GET['page']) ? 1 : $_GET['page']);
$show = 9;
```

You can impose the max `$page` number for free/paid users

```
if ($data['user']['membership']['name'] == 'free' AND $pageNumber > 1) {
    $pageNumber = 1;
}
else if ($data['user']['membership']['name'] == 'paid' AND $pageNumber > 3) {
    $pageNumber = 3;
}
```

Then you need to find the starting point of your limit.

```
$startLimit = ($pageNumber-1)*$show;
```

Now adding this to your query:

```
"SELECT * FROM profilevisitors WHERE user_id=".$id." LIMIT " .$startLimit. " , " . $show
```